# Node.js and Forever "exited with code: 0"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forever

CentOs 6.5 using root acount, I have a working Node.js Express app:

```
root@vps [/home/test/node]# npm start app.js
> test@0.0.1 start /home/test/node
> node ./bin/www app.js
```

The app can be seen working on the internet browser. I stop the app and try to run it with forever:

```
root@vps [/home/test/node]# forever start app.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
root@vps [/home/test/node]#
```

Throws a couple of warnings that should not be a problem and looks like it should be working but its not showing on the browser, forever list:

```
root@vps [/home/test/node]# forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script forever pid   id logfile                 uptime
data:    [0] OkGm /usr/local/bin/node app.js 32222   32227    /root/.forever/OkGm.log STOPPED
root@vps [/home/test/node]#
```

If I check OkGm.log:

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
```

Why is the app not working when I run it with forever?

Comment: The reason for the exit of your application should be right before the line `error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0` in your logs. Most likely an `EACCES` error or something similar.

Comment: @t.niese There is nothing more in the log file, only that line. When I try to run it again forever creates another log file with a different name with the same line again.

Comment: Then you either suppress an error message with a `try`-`catch` block or an `on('error', ...)` without handling it in a way that it informs you that the express server (?)  will be started. Or you do a check if you can start it which does not succeed and you don't start it as of that. Not matter what the reason is, its only you that can find out why. I would suggest to add some logging into your app. So that you can detect which steps are executed and which are not.

Answer (score 17):

Ok I found out what was happening. I was trying to run:

```
forever start app.js
```

When this Express app must be started with:

```
 forever start ./bin/www
```

There was no useful info on internet when searching for this by the error log output ("exited with code: 0"), so I hope this answer helps begginers like me in what I think can be an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Hey, I think I'm having the same issue, getting the same error. But I can't see any logs, and get the message saying no services are running when I try to `forever list`

Comment: So, how did you actually run your file? was it like `./bin/www/app.js` ?

Comment: This solution is really a life-saver. There is no documentation (at least I couldn't find one) about how to apply *forever* on a nodejs project generated from express-generator.

Comment: WOW, another fav to my browser!! thanks for the help now my app is up and running. this was outstanding!