# Forever detected script exited with code: 0

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a `app4.js` with content:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

I'm on `Win10 cmd`, I can success run it with `node app4.js` and get `Example app listening on port 3000!`,

but when I use `forever -a forever.log start app4.js`, it show error

> Forever detected script exited with code: 0

Where is the problem? How to solve it?

Cmd Message:

```
D:\app>node app4.js
Example app listening on port 3000!
^C
D:\app>forever -a forever.log start app4.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
```

[Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276996/node-js-and-forever-exited-with-code-0) say it's related to `./bin/www`, but I can't understand what does it mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try I got it, here's my complete tring process:

1.In the beginning, I'm watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R936XadXqfU) to learn `forever`, and at `10:24` it use `forever start server.js` and successfully run the server file.

---

2.Theoretically if I use `forever start app4.js` it should success, but I got  error:

```
D:\app>forever start app4.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app4.js
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   log file C:\Users\admin\.forever\forever.log exists. Use the -a or --append option to append log.
```

---

3.By the message, I think I should use `-a` to append log to some file, so I create a log file `forever2.log` under current folder, and use `forever -a forever2.log start app4.js`, the I got the error:

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
```

---

4.After some try, suddenly I look carefully to the nodejs book I'm reading, its example is `forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log app.js`, that is the `-x` is put between `start` and `app.js`, so I changed the command to `forever start -a forever2.log app4.js` and got

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: forever2.log
```

That is it's processing `forever2.log`, but what I want is `app4.js`

---

5.Finally I try `forever start -a app4.js`, and I got

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app4.js
```

Then I run Browser at `http://localhost:3000/`, the **Hello World!** finally show!

Answer (score 0):

It means try moving your app.js code to the www file in the bin directory.

in .bin/www

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Also seems to be a known bug on certain versions of node/forever.

[Issue](https://github.com/zapty/forever-service/issues/31)